# How to monitor network speed for an office

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet-speed

So I wrote a python script that calls a network speed test and gets the download speed, upload speed, and ping. However I realized that this won't be accurate since it's only the stats based on my own local machine. Sometimes we have users who can't connect to the internet at times, so it's hard to gauge if the issue is on their end of the network itself. I was thinking of moving the script to another external device like a raspberry pi or something and connecting that directly to the modem or router.

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Network speed tests are not the way to troubleshoot network issues. They are handy as a meaningful metric for a specific set of needs (what is the raw throughput of my internet connection) but that information does not communicate the amount of traffic on the network, the state of the links on the network, or many other more useful things. If someone doesn't have internet access, running a speedtest isn't how you troubleshoot the issue. I'd guess it is very possible to script a speed test and run that from a Pi, I'd just question "why?".

Comment: You should try a device like this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/RJ45-Patch-Cable-Tester-Continuity/dp/B005Y37MHC

Answer (score 0):

You could consider setting up a separate system, such as the Raspberry Pi you mention, to run Tobi Oetikers SmokePing. See: http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/index.en.html

Once installed and configured SmokePing will run continuously as a server, collecting latency/performance information for different services or protocols and generating graphs to help visualise the results.

SmokePing requires a UNIX/Linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are refering to Internet usage.

You could enable **SNMP** on router, and show effective network usage of Internet link, with the help of **MRTG or CACTI**. Also you could use something like **speedtest** to measure maximun bandwith usage of Internet link.